# How to deal with symbolic links when going between Linux and Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, django, symlink

I have a django project that runs on a Linux server, and I've been working on it both on Linux and OS X. I've noticed that some of the pages are a bit off, to put it politely, in Internet Explorer, and so I checked out the subversion repository on Windows and tried to run a local server.

My media directory has symbolic links to all of the media from each different app, and obviously Windows doesn't know what to do with them. I could simply hard-copy or link everything manually in Windows, but then I wouldn't be able to check that in (since the site runs on a Linux server), so it'd be a pain in the neck.

What is typically done in this case?

Comment: I'd avoid trying to get the server environment running under Windows just to test in IE. Just run a server on the LAN and connect to it from Windows running on another machine (or VM - I keep a couple of Windows installs on my Mac with Virtual Box).

Comment: @David, if I have a server running on 127.0.0.1:8000 on one of my machines, how can I connect to it from another?

Comment: — you can't. Run it on a IP address that is accessible from the LAN instead.

Comment: @David, I didn't know that was possible, but I tried it, and it worked - thanks! Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, of running a server on Windows just to test for IE, you can run a server from on an IP that identifies your machine on your network. Just run

```
python manage.py runserver ad.dr.re.ss:8000
```

To find the (local) address of your machine, access your router logs to see who's connected (I'm sure there's a better way, but this worked for me).

Comment: better way would be to bind to `0.0.0.0:8000` (all interfaces), and use `ipconfig` to get IP address

Answer (score 0):

Set up a configuration using httpd and mod_wsgi that has appropriate `Alias` directives for the static media.

Comment: But when I run the app locally, I'm just using `python manage.py runserver`, which doesn't use Apache (unless I'm misunderstanding you)

Comment: It is possible to run httpd locally. A Win32 version does exist.

Answer (score 0):

you could also add some static.serve links in your urls.py for debugging purpose :

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)/?$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root':settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes':True})
)
```

quicker than setting up apache+friends on win32.

Comment: I'm actually doing this for testing locally, even on Linux or OS X - but I still use the main media directory as the target, which contains all the symbolic links.